# Working towards going 3D

Tags: opengl, c++, sdl

I am a beginner-intermediate C++/Java programmer and my long term goal is to be a game programmer.

I have decided to start off with 2D and work my way towards 3D.

I would like to use SDL to start off with, but I am wondering if it is maybe not such a great idea.

Given the fact that I am working towards 3D, would it be advisable to use SDL or jump into OpenGL without the Z axis?

Answer (score 2):

Just use SDL.  You can use OpenGL with the SDL when you want to transition over.

http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/guidevideoopengl.html

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL is used quite a lot for 2D games. We used it in [Teeworlds](http://teeworlds.com) for example. Using it as a pure 2D language is ok, it might give you some quirks when setting up camera and especially if you want stuff pixel perfect. But you will learn a lot by doing it.

You can use OpenGL with SDL, it's very common. Most people doing it that way only uses GL though, and skips most (all?) of SDL:s drawing functions.